# css how to align header rotate table

Tags: html, css

I need rotate header table with css and keep all text together
Here my css

```css
th.rotate {
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate>div {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
       
     <th class="rotate"><div>Tintoria</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate"><div>Mag.Tops</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate"><div>Mag.Filati</div></th>                            
                    <th class="rotate"><div>Orditura</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate"><div>Tessitura</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate"><div>Ramm./Contr.</div></th>
```

and now this is result
[image]

My question is : how can i do reduce to 0 all spaces between buttons ???

my goal is that :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGhvI.png)

Comment: Please convert your ASP to HTML so that we can run the snippet. Though this has been asked and answered many times before and will probably be closed.

Comment: <table><tr><th class="rotate"><div>Tintoria</div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div>Mag.Tops</div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div>Mag.Filati</div></th>                            
                        <th class="rotate"><div>Orditura</div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div>Tessitura</div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div>Ramm./Contr.</div></th>

Comment: There is an edit button under your question. "Edit" -> "Edit this snippet"

Answer (score 1):

Use `writing-mode`:

> The writing-mode CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically, as well as the direction in which blocks progress.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)</sup>

```css
th.rotate {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate div {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th class="rotate">
    <div>Tintoria</div>
  </th>
  <th class="rotate">
    <div>Mag.Tops</div>
  </th>
  <th class="rotate">
    <div>Mag.Filati</div>
  </th>
  <th class="rotate">
    <div>Orditura</div>
  </th>
  <th class="rotate">
    <div>Tessitura</div>
  </th>
  <th class="rotate">
    <div>Ramm./Contr.</div>
  </th>
</table>
```